# How can I restyle a submit button?

Tags: css, form-submit

In one of the page of my ASP.NET MVC application, I have a list of messages that is shown to user. Something like this:

[image]

Pressing the close button marks the message as read on server so that it is not displayed again. This close button is internally a "submit" type input since I understand that any server side changes must be triggered by a form post.

I want to display this close as small "X" in the top right corner of message box. How can I style it like that? or there are other better ways to do it?

Answer (score 3):

use css.

```
.as_link {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px;
    color: red;
    float: right;
    etc...
}
```

Etc.

Edit: just re-read your question. Use the above but call it "x", I'm not sure that you're going to be using this for a web .net app (as I'm not familliar with the way of .net but if you are it will work, else ignore me :) )

Answer (score 2):

Use an `<input type="image" ... />` tag:

```
<input type="image" src="/path/to/image.file" alt="Alt text" />
```

It acts as a submit button, but displays an image instead.